# ISV Solutions Competency or Custom Development Solutions Competency?

Tags: .net

My company wants to apply Microsoft Gold Certified Partner. But, we not sure which competency should we take. Either goes to ISV Solutions Competency or Custom Development Competency.

Let me introduce my company background. We are third party healthcare service provider where we developed our own web based system to manage healthcare claims. We developed our system using Visual Studio .NET and .NET Framework 2.0. These system used by our internal employees because we also have 24 hours support centre to process the claims. We also open the system to external users (insurance company, hospitals, clinics and they pay the monthly fee) accessing through our VPN connection. We also sell our system to other insurance company.

So, which one more suitable for us? Go for ISV or Custom Development Competency?

Answer (score 1):

You would be an ISV - you have one packaged application that you provide and sell to your customers.  Custom Development competency is for firms providing custom software development services - building custom applications to your customer's requirements.